# Using an iterator twice in java

Tags: java, eclipse, arraylist, iterator

I'm new to ArrayLists and Iterators. I was trying out a simple implementation of an ArrayList inside an ArrayList.

I created an ArrayList called bug which has many ArrayLists inside it called memory. The memory ArrayList is simply a random integer.
Here is the code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Random;

public class TestList {
public static void main(String args[]){
    int N=5;
 //outer ArrayList
    ArrayList<ArrayList> bug = new ArrayList<ArrayList>();
    for(int i=0 ; i<N ; i++)
    {
        //inner ArrayList
        ArrayList memory = new ArrayList();
        bug.add(memory);
    }

    Iterator<ArrayList> outer = bug.iterator();
    while(outer.hasNext())
    {
        ArrayList memory = outer.next();
        memory.add(new Random().nextInt(10));               
    }


    while(outer.hasNext())
    {
        ArrayList memory = outer.next();
        Iterator inner = memory.iterator(); 

        System.out.println(inner.next());
    }   

}
}
```

This does not print anything. However if I create another iterator for bug(for a display purpose) such as outer01 then the code works.

```
Iterator<ArrayList> outer01 = bug.iterator();
    while(outer01.hasNext())
    {
        ArrayList memory = outer01.next();
        Iterator inner = memory.iterator(); 

        System.out.println(inner.next());
    }
```

So my question is this - does an iterator "run out" when it reaches the end of an Array List?And if so, is there any way to send it back to the start of the list?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it "runs out."  You will *have* to create a new iterator, e.g. with doing `outer = bug.iterator()` again.

(If you had gotten a `ListIterator` you could walk it backwards with `previous()`, but this will frankly take much longer and be much more wasteful than just getting a new iterator.)

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Iterators do not loop back to the beginning. In your first code sample, there still isn't a next object when you reach your second while loop's conditional.  Essentially, the iterator has no knowledge (or context) that it's being asked "hasNext" for another loop.